# git revert and update a submodule

Tags: git

I have two repositories

```
dir <repo A>
      |
      ------ dir <repo B> which is a sub module in repo A
```

repo A uses repo B as a sub module 
I am trying to revert repo B to a certain point in time, and afterward update repo A to use that hash as a checkout point for the sub module

I tried to do

```
git checkout repo_b_revert_hash
```

but this results in no branch if I do git branch.

I tried

```
git revert repo_b_revert_hash
```

but this just creates another commit in my repo , and not removing any changes.

I am also confused what to do next, cause I cannot go to the repo A directory and do checkout repoB because this will go back to the old point in time in which repo b is before the revert.

Any ideas? Do I need to clarify myself more?

Answer (score 0):

Found out a way to do so, but not sure it is the best way

in repo b

```
git checkout hash_for_revert
```

afterward

```
git checkout master
```

go to repo A directory

```
git commit repo B dir
git push
```